# How to set a Preference icon only when the Preference is shown?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, settings, preferencescreen

I have a settings fragment which builds its list of `Preference` objects dynamically and adds them to the `PreferenceScreen` object. The list is quite big, roughly 100 items. I want each of the preferences to have an icon.

The problem that I am having is that I often run into out of memory issues because `Preference.setIcon` allocates the memory for the drawable right as you call it.

I would like the icon not to be shown, until the preference is actually shown. Is this possible?